# Execution order of goroutines

Tags: go

I am very new to golang.

My understanding is, All the go-routines will be executed concurrently. both anonymous goroutines will start executing concurrently.
but when i run this code, It always prints

```
a=1 first executed
a=1 second executed
panic: b != 1
```

Shouldnt it print

```
a = 1
a = 1 first executed 
Response true
and so on
```

or

```
b =1 
b = 1 first executed 
Response true
and so on
```

Since after sending a value to the channel, the corresponding goroutine should block and wait for the receiver?

```
 func main() {
            var a, b int
            var c = make(chan bool)
            go func() {
                b = 1
                fmt.Println("b=1 first executed")
                c <- true
                fmt.Println("b=1 second executed")
                if a != 1 { // impossible
                    panic("a != 1") // will never happen
                }
                fmt.Println("b=1 third executed")
            }()
            go func() {
                a = 1
                fmt.Println("a=1 first executed")
                c <- true
                fmt.Println("a=1 second executed")
                if b != 1 { // impossible
                    panic("b != 1") // will never happen
                }
                fmt.Println("a=1 third executed")
            }()

            fmt.Println("Response ", <-c)
            fmt.Println("Main executed")
            }
```

Comment: whats the value of GOMAXPROCS?

Comment: Havent defined GOMAXPROCs

Comment: I don't see why you expect it to print "a = 1" or "b = 1". There's nothing in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming you are running on Playground. There is one thing to keep in mind when using Go Playground: **It has a fixed time and a fixed psedo-random generator.**

That means, You can not use Playground to observe random outcomes. And the execuation order of Goroutine, or Go's Concurrency concept in general, is based on uniform psedo-random-ness.

Running your code on my terminal, it yields different results:

```
➜  basic1 GOMAXPROCS=1 ./basic1
a=1 first executed
a=1 second executed
a=1 third executed
Response  true
Main executed
➜  basic1 GOMAXPROCS=1 ./basic1
a=1 first executed
a=1 second executed
panic: b != 1

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.main.func2(0xc000012088, 0xc000054060, 0xc0000120a0)
        /mnt/f/home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concur/basic1/main.go:26 +0x13b
created by main.main
        /mnt/f/home/leaf/spike/stackoverflow/concur/basic1/main.go:20 +0xed
➜  basic1 GOMAXPROCS=1 ./basic1
a=1 first executed
a=1 second executed
a=1 third executed
b=1 first executed
Response  true
Main executed
```

But there's something more. As I have metioned, Go's concurrent excecution order is random. There is no guarantee which goes first, unless there is a synchronization.

Synchronizations includes channel communicating, and stuffs from `sync`.

There is only one synchronization happening in your code, which is communicating through `c`. It guarantees one thing: when the `main()` goroutine recieves its `Response`, **at least** one of the goroutines spawned there has printed its "excecuated".

**There is no guarantee that which of one is execuated, nor both or only one is execuated, nor whether the goroutine hits the `if` statement containing `panic` first**.

Edit:

Further reading:

- Some good reading on Go's current scheduler: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part1.html
- Go's own documention on memory model which explains "happens before" and execuation order: https://golang.org/ref/mem

Comment: It would be appreciated that anyone can explain on the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The only synchronization between these tow goroutines ist via a send on `c`. As only one value is ever read from c only one of the two send operations `c <- true` goes through while the other blocks forever.

Lets assume the first goroutine runs first (by chance), and does the send and both Printlns while the second goroutine did not start executing at all. This is a valide mode of operation and will produce the output you see.

Your synchronization via `c` is **not** between the two anonymous goroutines, but between the goroutines and the outer `f3` only.

Comment: c <- true from any of the goroutines isnt blocking and not shifting the execution to the receiver which is Main thread. why?

Comment: One of  the `c <- true` is executed when the `<-c` at the end of f3 is executed. Which one is _undetermined_. The other `c <- true` blocks for ever. A channel send or receive **does** **not** shift execution between goroutines! This is a completely wrong model of what actually happens.

Comment: A channel send or receive does not shift execution between goroutines!  Then what blocking means?
I think, when a channel blocks for send or receive, it looks for goroutines or main function which can push or pull to the channel.

If you have any link, which i can read, then it would be of great help.

Comment: Blocking means that a certain statement is not executed. Concrete here the channel send. The send is executed once any corresponding receive from the (unbuffered) channel is executed. Formally the send even "happens before" (memory wise) than the receive. See https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7, best the whole document. It is not helpful to rely too much on some implementation detail or on wrong assumptions.